# Cargo - adjust stacked page height

Tags: html, css, menu, stacked

I'm designing a page for my mobile menu using stacked pages for the 4 pages I'm linking to - how can I make each of these pages 25% so that the coloured blocks fill up the whole page? :)

As you can see right now they are taking up a small percentage of the screen so there's a lot of white space

[image: screenshot]

I'm afraid nothing as I'm new to building sites...

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: I think this is it? Apologies if not! 

[data-css-preset] .content_padding {
 padding-top: 2rem /*!main_margin*/;
 padding-bottom: 2rem /*!main_margin*/;
 padding-left: 2rem /*!main_margin*/;
 padding-right: 2rem /*!main_margin*/;
"height: 25%;">}

Comment: Also your html :) I can only see the picture.. maybe you can edit your post and add all your code or add something like a codepen

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.